# How to get the Quote from an Intel SGX Enclave

Tags: intel, sgx, trusted-computing

I am developing a trusted computing project with the help of an Intel SGX Enclave.

To verify an Enclave i need the Quote generated by the Quoting-Enclave.

I know how it works theoretically and how to start an Enclave.
But I am not able to find any code examples or detailed explanation on how to recieve the quote for an Enclave and sending it to the calling programm.

Can someone please explain that to me through an example?

Comment: Are you using the raw SGX SDK or some library wrapper that hides the complexity of SGX, e.g. [Gramine](https://github.com/gramineproject/gramine)? If you are using the raw SGX SDK, you need to call [`sgx_qe_get_quote`](https://download.01.org/intel-sgx/sgx-dcap/1.7/linux/docs/Intel_SGX_ECDSA_QuoteLibReference_DCAP_API.pdf). [Here](https://github.com/intel/SGXDataCenterAttestationPrimitives/blob/master/SampleCode/QuoteGenerationSample/App/App.cpp) is an example. If you are using Gramine, see [this](https://github.com/gramineproject/gramine/blob/master/libos/test/regression/attestation.c).

Answer (score -2):

Well, what you are trying to do is called *Attestation*.

Attestation is a process to verify:

1. whether an enclave is running the expected bynaries (signed library), *and*,
2. whether *it is* running in a real SGX enabled processor.

Attestation usually is required prior to providing secrets to an enclave. This process is called *Provisioning*.

There are two kinds of Attestation:

- *Local Attestation*: two enclaves, running on the same Platform (PC) want to *"verify"* each other.
- *Remote Attestation*: a Service Provicer needs to verify an enclave remotely.

You mention *Quote Enclave (QE)* so I suppose you are using *Remote attestation*.

If you are searching for examples, please refer to the example projects comming with the Intel SGX SDK, or the ones available at the [Intel SGX site](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx/code-samples).

Comment: You can learn more about attestation from [Enclave Writers Guide](http://cwfletcher.net/Content/598/Software-Guard-Extensions-Enclave-Writers-Guide.pdf)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all. The question was what the API/protocol is to request the quote from the Quoting Enclave.